# Convert text timestamp to date

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

I have a time stamp of the form `1518427677000` in a MySQL database. The type of the field in the database is TEXT. I would like to convert this value to DATETIME  in MySQL Query.

I tried with CAST, CONVERT, STR_TO_DATE, date_format, FROM_UNIXTIME and UNIX_TIMESTAMP but all these functions return either an error or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1518427677000` looks like UNIX Epoch... in milliseconds. Just divide it by 1000:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME('1518427677000' / 1000)
-- 2018-02-12 14:27:57
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your timestamp is in milliseconds. User FROM_UNIXTIME after dividing by 1000:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME (1518427677)
```